# Using the chain rule to solve reciprical of a function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, products

Here is my issue.

To prove the quotient rule from the product rule, we require the use of chain rule on $(h(x))^{-1}$. Why?

For example, if $h(x)=3x^{-1}$, then $h'(x)=-3x^{-2}$

However, the chain rule says $\frac{d}{dx} (h(x))^{-1} = -1(h(x))^{-2} h'(x)$, which would suggest for $h(x)=3x^{-1}$, then $h'(x)=-3(3x^{-2})$

Comment: Haha! Is my careless mistake that h(x)=3x^-1 \neq to h(x)=1/3 * 1/x

Answer (score 1):

In your solution, $\frac{d}{dx}h(x)^{-1}$
i.e. $h(x) = \frac{1}{3}x$ not $3x^{-1}$

Comment: Thanks, i thought that was my mistake, can you apply the chain rule to this so i am 100% clear

Comment: of course, $d/dx (h(x))^{-1} = -(h(x))^{-2} * h'(x)$, where here $h(x) = 1/3 * x$
Then $h'(x) = 1/3$, Then $d/dx (h(x))^{-1} = -(1/3 * x)^{-2} * 1/3 = -9/3 * x^{-2} = -3x^{-2}$

Answer (score 0):

I can give an example let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ so  by product rule $f'(x)=1'x^{-1}+1.(x^{-1})'=\frac{-1}{x^2}$ and by normal derivative rule $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}$ we get the same result. And chain rule we get the same result. In your example f'(x) for $3x^{-1}$ is $-3x^{-1-1}.3x'$ is correct.  In chain rule you didnt differentiate $3x$ so you are getting different results.so $f'(3x^{-1})=-1.3x^{-2}.(3x)'=-3.(3x^{-2})$

Comment: Can you diff (3x)^-1 using the chain rule for me please

Comment: Ya i edit ny answsr